# auto increment of number in terraform

Tags: numbers, auto-increment

actually i am trying to provision ec2 instance from ServiceNow catalog through terraform script. when provisioned the ec2 instance the name will be something be like abc001A , second time when trying to provision ec2 using i want the name will be like abce002A ,  how could i achieve this auto number increment with terraform.

count = 1
Name = "${local.value1}count.index+1}"